# D7 Views: Hide field if empty after being rewritten

Tags: 7, views, entities

In a node type, I have three fields: (1) methods, (2) geography, (3) keywords.
On node view, I have a views block showing these values. However, I want all of the content to appear as single field with a label. This was easy to achieve:
(a) exclude methods and geography from display, (2) rewrite keywords to display the content of methods and geography.

This works like a charm as long as any of the three fields is not empty. However, if all three fields are empty, the block still displays the label (Keywords).

**How should I setup the view to hide the label if there is no data in any field?**

I've been playing around with all sorts of combinations of the hide options, besides "Hide when empty" and "Hide rewriting when empty" it seems like I would need an option "Hide IF rewrite is empty".

More details reagarding the view:

Format: Unformatted list

Show: Fields

Fields

- Methods: no label, exclude from display
- Geography: no label, exclude from display
- Keywords: label "Keywords", rewrite results: [keywords][methods][geography]

Comment: It's working fine from myside. Can you provide the details like what's your Views Format? or simply provide a screenshot of the views output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your view and Click on Keywords to configure the field.

Go to *No results behavior* and check *Hide if empty*

[image]

That's it. I've tested it and it's working fine. Let me know if you stuck anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I didn't see the wood for the trees. You are absolutely right, this is the way it works. However, to add to my problem I wanted to have all terms comma separated. But that's another issue.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, let me know if you stuck with another issue. I'll do my best to help you. :)

Comment: I've added a follow-up question at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/130728/d7-views-rewrite-multiple-field-into-one-with-custom-separators Any idea would be appreciated.